# Search a string on some other page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, search, html

Can anyone suggest a way to search a string on the web page, using ASP .net C#

Scenario: A textbox have some value(string), and on the click of button it searches that value(string) on some xyz page.

Example: I have "youtube"(string) in the textbox, and when I press submit button. That submit button gets the entire information of say Google.com(rendered page), and searches for "youtube"(string) on that Google.com

Possible solution:
I think that can be achieved by some-how rendering the page temporarily some-where, or some-how storing the response in any string or array, and then look that string.

Can anyone suggest a way to solve the above scenario. If possible with an example.

Answer (score 0):

use a web request to get the page:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(http://www.google.com);
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

then just search on your `content` string:

```
int i = content.IndexOf("youtube");
```

or however you want to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with async/await if you are using .NET 4.5

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var content = GetUrlContents("http://www.google.com");

        if (content.Result.Contains("Google"))
            Console.WriteLine("Google found!");

        Console.Read();
    }

    static async Task<string> GetUrlContents(string url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

        return content;
    }
```

Or if you want synchronous, you could do this kind of method

```
    public static string GetUrlContents(string url)
    {
        return new WebClient().DownloadString(address);
    }
```